# Can this mongoDB action be made more efficient?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a collection that looks like:

```
[
  {
    'job': builder,
    'name': bob
  },
  {
    'job': doctor,
    'name': bob
  },
  {
    'job': builder,
    'name': james
  },
  {
    'job': lawyer,
    'name': james
  },
  ...
]
```

I also have an array where job is always the same, like:

```
[
  {
    'job': builder,
    'name': jack
  },
  {
    'job': builder,
    'name': john
  },
  ...
]
```

I want to replace all objects in my collection where job is builder. To do this I am currently using two separate queries.

```
mycollection.remove({'job': builder})
mycollection.insert(new_job_array);
```

Is there a way to combine this into one query?

Comment: What do you want to replace them with? Specific consistent changes to all documents?

Comment: @WiredPrairie I want to replace them all with the new array. The example is perhaps illogical but the aim is to create a completely fresh set of data.

Comment: OK -- they need to be done as distinct steps then. There's no particular benefit to doing it as one operation really given the nature of the changes you're making (other than avoiding a second network request, which in the big scheme of things, would be "noise" in the overall process).

Comment: It's a busy table so the benefit would have been preventing other processes hitting the table at the point where it is empty (after the remove and before the insert completes). Although that's never going to be completely prevented I thought it might have been reduced by a single query vs. one. That and it's just cleaner to have one operation. But, hey ho, 2 it is then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `update` command.

`mycollection.update({'job':'builder'}, {new document}, {multi:true})`

More information here: [MongoDB update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/modify-documents/)

Comment: You cannot update multiple documents if the second parameter does not contain update operators (such as `$inc`). So, as described, it does not work.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Agreed, I tried this solution and it does not solve the problem as described.

Answer (score 0):

The end result is that, no, there is not one operation that does this. 2 steps are required and it should use really use a callback.

```
mycollection.remove({'job': builder}, function(err){
  if ( err ) handle();
  else mycollection.insert(new_job_array);
});
```